# Page Templates automatically showing index page contents?

Tags: page-template

So I'm taking my first foray into creating a wordpress page template. I created a .php file with the following contents:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Download Page Template
*/
?>
```

Then I created a page in the page editor and assigned it to use the "download page template". However, when I preview this page, all I see is the home/index page ... I tried a few of the samples from [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages), but all that happened is that my content from the wp editor showed up at the very bottom of the index page.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted above is all of your file contents then Yes you are missing something!

you just created a new page template but it's empty, you need to tell WordPress what to display, and usually its done using [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and a few other template tags add this code to you a.php under what you already have :

```
//this will include the theme header.php file
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div id="content" class="widecolumn">

 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
    <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <div class="entrytext">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

</div>

//this will include the theme footer.php file
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: darn, should have mentioned ... I tried precisely this content (from the codex) before I posted here and got the same results :-) in either case, even if it was empty, I would expect an empty screen, not the entire contents of the front page ;-)

Comment: what custom query - if any - are using before the loop in your page template?

Comment: none ... whether I use the above mentioned script, or just a blank "template name", it renders the whole front page